# Inserir botões para compartilhar posts no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso inserir botões nos rodapés dos posts para que o mesmo seja compartilhado pelas redes sociais e whatsapp, já instalei diversos Plugins mas não atenderam a minha necessidade, ou existe uma forma de utilizar os links contidos nas páginas estáticas e no cabeçalho que por sua vez já possuem os botões das redes sociais usados no tema?

Comment: Sua questão resolve-se com plugins, mas dizes que não funciona. Podes dar mais detalhes? Os plugins funciona am com u outro tema?

Comment: Olá,
Quais foram os plugins que testaste? Experimentaste o addThis? Cumps,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns plugins que fazer isso de maneira simples. Não sei exatamente quais são as redes sociais que você deseja compartilhar, mas com base no que você falou posso citar alguns plugins que apresentam um maior número de usuários.

- [AddToAny Share Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-to-any/)
- [Simple Share Buttons Adder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/)
- [ShareThis: Free Sharing Buttons and Tools](https://wordpress.org/plugins/share-this/)

Qualquer coisa, você pode encontrar mais alguns plugins [nessa listagem](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/share-buttons).

Outra possibilidade é usar o esquema dos botões de compartilhamento fornecido pelo [JetPack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) (caso já o use).

Comment: agora adicionei o plugin AddToAny e funcionou perfeitamente inclusive para whatsapp, pode ser alguma incompatibilidade do tema com os outros plugins. obrigado @HamurabiAraujo

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado. Como essa resposta te foi útil na solução do problema, marque-a como correta. Ajudará na resolução de problemas semelhantes de outras pessoas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, já utilizei plugins para isso mas a melhor solução que encontrei foi fazer na mão, fica mais leve e mais simples para personalizar.
$GLOBALS['url'] = "url do seu template";

```
<div id="compartilhamento">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/whatsapp.png"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>&amp;t=<?php echo urlencode(the_title('','', false)) ?>" target="_blank" title="Compartilhar <?php the_title();?> no Facebook"><img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/facebook.png"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php the_title();?>&url=<?php the_permalink();?>&via=seutwitter" title="Twittar sobre <?php the_title();?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/twitter.png"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/google-plus.png"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink();?>&title=<?php the_title();?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/linkedin.png"></a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- <li>
                                <a href="#"><img src="<?php //echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/pinterest.png"></a>
                            </li> -->
                            <li>
                            <a target="_blank" class="email" title="Compartilhe por Email" href="mailto:?Subject=<?php the_title();?>&amp;Body=http%3A%2F%2Fwptotal.com.br%2Fcomo-adicionar-botao-de-compartilhamento-no-seu-blog%2F"></a>
                                <a href="mailto:?Subject=<?php the_title();?>&amp;Body=<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/mail.png"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:window.print()"><img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['url']; ?>/images/print.png"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: gostei da sua idéia e o meu caminho será este, mas como estava com urgência acabei utilizando o plugin AddToAny que atendeu a minha necessidade, obrigado.

Comment: boa noite tudo bem, utilizei o plugin AddToAny no primeiro momento funcionou mas o botão whatsapp não funciona no navegador tem alguma idéia? já instalei o aplicativo de desktop mesmo assim o mesmo não é iniciado.

Comment: Realmente, no navegador ele não consegue identificar o app desktop instalado, ainda não consegui resolver isso tbm.